# Is thenApply() is dependent on the firstMethod only?

Tags: java-8, completable-future

```
public class Test {

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> firstMethod(int x) {
        // Assume this method completes in 8sec.
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("In first method");
            return x + 10;
        });

    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Integer> secondMethod(int y) {
        System.out.println("This line will be printed only when firstMethod get completed?");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("In second method");
            return y + 10;
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        firstMethod(5)
                .thenApply(fromfirst -> secondMethod(fromfirst))
                .thenAccept(x -> System.out.println(x));
    }
}
```

Do `firstMethod` must have to be completed then only, `thenApply()` method get chance to run. Then i can say whatever code that get executed inside the `thenApply()` get its chance only when `firstMethod` finish its execution. So it is behaving synchronously like when A finish then B get run.
If that is the case why `thenApply()` run on separate thread?

My Assumptions:
What i am thinking, that `thenApply()` should run irrespective of its previous method is completed or not. But wondering for example say, what happen when output from first method is required as the input for the second method in `thenApply()`.

Comment: I’ve read your post twice and still don’t know what your question is.

Comment: Hi @Holger I have improved the question. Can you please check

Comment: It’s still not clear what you’re asking. The purpose of chaining a *dependent* action is precisely to perform the action only after the prerequisite stage has been completed. That’s what *dependent* means. In case of `thenApply`, the thread performing the action is *unspecified*. It’s not said that it will be a “separate thread”.

Answer (score 0):

- Doc says:

> **thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)**
>
> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the
> supplied function.

Important is **when this stage completes**.

- *why `thenApply()` run on separate thread*.

Who said that?

I suspect that you are troubled by the fact that the final output shows something like `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@6ad3e7be[Not completed]`. As you embed *async* computations into the `CompletionStage`s, there may be some asynchronous computations but not those you think.

`fromfirst -> secondMethod(fromfirst)` is sequenced after the delivery of the result of `firstMethod`, the fact that `secondMethod` constructs an *async*  computation is of no interest from that point of view.

There may be a delay in between sending the output of the first stage to the second, and the marking of the first as `Completed`, that's all. Add some waiting into the last printing and see:

```
.thenAccept(x -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // wait a little bit
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(x);
});
```

As there will be probably enough time to mark everything correctly, you will see `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@6ad3e7be[Completed normally]`

You may also try a join:

```
.thenAccept(x -> {
    int i = x.join(); // synchronous waiting of the end and get the result.
    System.out.println(x +" ------ "+ i);
});
```